# Issues copying values to new google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm helping out a friend that has a master spreadsheet with a lot of data. He wants some of the data to be easily accessed by others via another spreadsheet, that will pull the necessary data when accessed.

The spreadsheets are accessed via Google Sheets, which I am admittedly not well versed in. However, after some research i came up with the following test code:

```
function makeAvailableSheet() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("TargetSheetID");

  var sourceSheetsArray=source.getSheets();
  var targetSheetsArray=target.getSheets();

  var sourceSheet
  var targetSheet

  var sourceRange;
  var targetRange;

  var sourceValues;

  var sourceSheetLastRow
  var targetSheetLastRow;

  var assignedRange;
  var loadedRange;

  var assignedValues;
  var loadedValues;

  //for loop here for(j=0,j<targetSheetsArray.length;j++)
  sourceSheet=source.getSheetByName("Test Source Sheet");
  //sourceSheet=sourceSheetsArray[j];
  targetSheet=target.getSheetByName("Test Target Sheet");
  //targetSheet=targetSheesArray[j];
  sourceSheetLastRow=sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  targetSheetLastRow=targetSheet.getLastRow();
  assignedRange=sourceSheet.getRange("A2:A"+sourceSheetLastRow);
  loadedRange=sourceSheet.getRange("L2:L"+sourceSheetLastRow);
  assignedValues=assignedRange.getValues();
  loadedValues=loadedRange.getValues();
  for(i=0;i<sourceSheetLastRow;i++){
    if(!assignedValues[i] && !loadedValues[i]){
        targetSheet.insertRowAfter(targetSheetLastRow);
        targetSheetLastRow=targetSheet.getLastRow();
        sourceRange=sourceSheet.getRange("B"+i+":F"+i);
        sourceValues=sourceRange.getValues();
        targetRange=targetSheet.getRange("A"+targetSheetLastRow+":E"+targetSheetLastRow);
        targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
      }
  }
}
```

The script should be checking 2 boolean values (assignedValues and loadedValues) if both are false, then a set of values should be copied over to the other sheet, but whenever I run the test it is deleting rows.

Edit: After some debug i realized that assignedValues and loadedValues were arrays of arrays., so i got around it by adding this to the for loop:

```
for(i = 2; i < sourceSheetLastRow-1; i++){
  isAssigned=(assignedValues[i-2])[0];
  isLoaded=(loadedValues[i-2])[0];
```

The script was posting some of the wrong data, but i fixed that. So my script now runs as intended for a single sheet, but with now I am trying to make the script runs for all sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function run1() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Target ID");
  var sshts=sss.getSheets();
  var tshts=tss.getSheets();
  var sshtsNameA=sshts.map(function(sh){return sh.getName();});
  tshts.forEach(function(tsh) {
    var tshtname=tsh.getName();
    var srcidx=sshtsNameA.indexOf(tshtname)
    if(srcidx>-1) {
      var ssh=sshts[srcidx];
      var colA=ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
      var colL=ssh.getRange(2,12,ssh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
      var svA=ssh.getRange(2,2,ssh.getLastRow()-1,5).getValues();
      var ovA=[];
      for(var i=0;i<svA.length;i++) {
        if(!colA[i][0] && !colL[i][0]) {
          ovA.push(svA[i]);
        }
      }
      tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,2,ovA.length,5).setValues(ovA);
    }
  });
}
```